# Is there a term for unimplemented code that was written for someone else to fill in?

Tags: terminology

Sometimes in a programming exercise, boilerplate generation, putting guide rails around the tasks for a junior programmer to implement, etc., it happens that the programmer is presented unimplemented code and told to "fill in the blank." For example, a unit test that may compile, but fails, or a class declaration with empty methods.

Is there a common term for this practice?

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking, but related. If there are also test scripts in place which show what your code is expected to do, then it's known as Test Driven Development.

Comment: To whomever voted to close: sure, "name this thing" might not be an especially _interesting_ question. However, this question does have an objective answer that is not primarily opinion-based. As proof, I present my answer below.

Comment: I would say "Terrible coding practice."

Comment: Second thing that comes to mind is a virtual class.

Comment: [NotImplementedException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notimplementedexception(v=vs.110).aspx) :)

Comment: "Exercise for the reader" seems to be the textbook approach if you're talking about error handling.

Comment: .NET has the concept of an interface, which defines what properties and methods a class that inherits from said interface must implement. Not quite what you're asking about, but it's a thing and built into the framework.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

You are referring to a *stub* or *skeleton*:

### [Stub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub)

This is typically a method or function with a mostly-empty body that simply returns a dummy value so code will compile.

### [Skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_%28computer_programming%29)

This is a method that has a high-level algorithm implemented, but individual parts are left unimplemented. They may be empty code blocks, or reference stub methods (see above) that will eventually perform subtasks. This is a good way to express a software design for a junior programmer who may struggle with the larger design effort, or for making sure you have the algorithm correct before investing too much time in the low-level details.

---

The practice of using these code elements would be called *stubbing* or *creating a code skeleton*.

Comment: Although I like your terms better, I think that the term 'scaffolding' in Ruby on Rails is the same concept.

Comment: I also thought stub was the right word for this, but was not sure because I was getting push back from others at my job. Thank you.

Comment: It's a "stub" if done in an academic context.  Done in a professional/commercial context, it's "technical debt".

Comment: @aroth it is not technical debt if the code does not work - it must be implemented. Technical debt implies _poorly written_ code that ends up being used in a production environment, meaning it requires significant effort to refactor correctly. A stub would ideally have a failing test case, so it _must_ be implemented and tested before being set loose on production.

Comment: @BrandonArnold: When talking to your colleges, you should use words they understand. Unless you are the boss.

Comment: @StigHemmer Well, if you're in a good working environment, *especially* when you're the boss :D

Comment: @StigHemmer When talking to a stranger, you shouldn't give them social skills advice. Unless they ask you to do so.

Comment: I think *skeleton*, not *stub*, matches the meaning OP is asking for. A skeleton is meant to be filled in. A stub is a non-functional implementation that's present to meet an interface requirement that's not actually needed or desired for the program at hand - it's a YAGNI phenomenon.

Answer (score 42):

I've seen the term “**stub**” being used.

For example, I believe that *Eclipse* automatically inserts a comment

```java
String getName() {
    // TODO: Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

into its infamous auto-generated, well, stubs.

Also note the usage of the term “stub” in the context of [unit testing](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html).

Comment: "// TODO: Auto-generated method stub" I think.

Comment: Definitely useful to know this. . .

Answer (score 17):

In Visual Studio, when writing code intellisense will give you the option "generate a new method stub". When you choose this option, Visual Studio will generate a stub/skeleton of code exactly as you have described.

Microsoft refers to this as a stub, so I would also call these stubs.